# Oracle - time and date format

Tags: oracle, date

I have an Oracle question, hope someone can guide me. I am using php and sql to select columns from a table. Part of the info I get is the time and date of when the column was created. For the moment I get the date in `DD-MM-YYYY` format. How can I change it so I can get it in `YYYY-MM-DD` format?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
SELECT TO_CHAR ( MyDateColumn, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) FROM MyTable
```